# phonegap custom camera capture on Android

Tags: android, camera, cordova

I am using Phonegap and my application is capturing a picture before uploading it.
Capturing a picture is no problem, but after the capture, my phone (motorola cliq) is displaying the image and offers me 2 choices: attach or cancel.

I would like to customize this view, and have the phone offering upload and cancel, and possibly change the icons, is that possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying to remove the confirmation dialogue and save the image by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap relies on native code for taking pictures, so if you want to create a custom camera capture view, you must provide an own PhoneGap plugin that is the written as regular Android Code and the use it from your PhoneGap app.